# Determine if the set $S=\{(x,y) : 1+ \sin^2 (xy)<3 \;\mathrm{and}\; x^2 + y^ 4 \leq1 \}$ is open or closed or neither?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have a set $S=\{(x,y) : 1+ \sin^2 (xy)<3 \;\mathrm{and}\; x^2 + y^ 4 \leq1 \}$.

How can I decide if it is open/closed/neither? I can't visualize and I can't graph it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin^2(\cdot)\in[0,1]$, the constraint $1+\sin^2(xy)<3$ is vacuous. Thus, your set is really just $\{(x,y):x^2+y^4\leq 1\}$, the closedness of which is now evident. ($S=f^{-1}((-\infty,1])$ where $f(x,y)=x^2+y^4$ is continuous.)

Comment: Nicely put, @yurnero.

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition is empty because $1+sin^2(a) <3$ for all $a$...

So $S = \{ (x,y) | x^2 + y^4 \leq1\}$. Let $f$ be the function $(x,y)\rightarrow x^2+y^4$. $f$ is continuous (because polynomial), and $S=f^{-1}(]-\infty; 1])$ so it is closed.

$\mathbb R^2$ is connected, so if $S$ is closed it is not open (if it was, it would be empty or all $\mathbb R^2$)